# Prevent image ignoring padding and border of a container

Tags: html, image, css, flexbox

I have an image and container for it. Image can center by horizontal and vertical in container. Also container has border and padding. But image ignore container vertical border and padding.

```css
a{
  display:-webkit-inline-flex;
  display:inline-flex;
  -webkit-justify-content:center;
  justify-content:center;
  -webkit-align-items:center;
  align-items:center;
  width:166px;
  height:146px;
  padding:8px;
  border-width:1px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#000;
}

a img{
  display:inline;
  width:auto;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="/">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
</a>
```

How can prevent this behaviour?

Comment: so you want img is fit in box, right? use background-image then.

Comment: @Leothelion That's right. I want to fit image in container. Background-image is unsuitable for me.

Comment: add `max-height: 100%` for `a img` is what you require ?

Comment: @kukkuz Thank you, this fix the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `max-height: 100%` to `a img` solves the issue.

See snippet below:

```css
a{
  display:-webkit-inline-flex;
  display:inline-flex;
  -webkit-justify-content:center;
  justify-content:center;
  -webkit-align-items:center;
  align-items:center;
  width:166px;
  height:146px;
  padding:8px;
  border-width:1px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#000;
}

a img{
  display:block;
  width:auto;
  max-width:100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="/">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add width img container instead of hyperlink

```css
a{
  display:-webkit-inline-flex;
  display:inline-flex;
  -webkit-justify-content:center;
  justify-content:center;
  -webkit-align-items:center;
  align-items:center;
  
  padding:8px;
  border-width:1px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#000;
}

a img{
  display:inline;
  max-width:100%;
  width:166px;
}
```

```html
<a href="/">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

like this code

```
  a{
 display:-webkit-inline-flex;
 display:inline-flex;
  -webkit-justify-content:center;
  justify-content:center;
 -webkit-align-items:center;
align-items:center;
padding:8px;
border-width:1px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#000;
height:auto;
}

a img{
max-width:100%;
width:166px;
height:144px;
}
<a href="/">
<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
```

Comment: Also as in @jogoe answear

Answer (score 0):

adding the `height` property fixes your problem.

```
a img{
  display:inline;
  width:auto;
  max-width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: In this an images width width > height is stretch not proportional

Answer (score 0):

Give `auto` to height and width of a tag

```css
a{
  display:-webkit-inline-flex;
  display:inline-flex;
  -webkit-justify-content:center;
  justify-content:center;
  -webkit-align-items:center;
  align-items:center;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  padding:8px;
  border-width:1px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#000;
}

a img{
  display:inline;
  width:auto;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="/">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
</a>
```